# Regex pattern for domain-part of URL

Tags: regex, actionscript

I am looking for a regex-pattern that matches the domain path of an url (http or https)

example 1:

```
 https://www.blabla.com/path/pic.jpg
```

should match

```
 https://www.blabla.com
```

example 2:

```
 http://my.domain.tld/directory/?something
```

should match

```
 http://my.domain.tld
```

Comment: Are you using a programming language (which?) or a tool (which?)? Many languages provide built-in functions to parse URLs.

Comment: @m.buettner yes i am using actionscript which afaik does not have an URL class but has a RegEx class.

Answer (score 2):

something along the lines:

```
#^(https?://[a-z0-9.-]+)(?=/|$).*#i
```

It depends of course which characters you'd like to allow in the domain name.

P.S. `#` are there to delimit the regex, `i` at the end indicates case-insensitivity.

Comment: won't it complain about your `/`s?

Comment: @silentghost Greets! can you explain the `-` 'function' in the regex? Thanks

Comment: @JosephMarikle: that's just to delimit the regex, there was no indication which flavour clamp was using when I posted my answer. Besides, I'm not familiar with details of actionscript regex syntax.

Comment: @cl-r: http://www.experts-exchange.com/ ? Not sure I understand your question otherwise.

Comment: @cl-r it's a character class (brackets indicate a character class) that includes word characters (\w), periods (.), or dashes(-)

Comment: @SilentGhost thanks! for starting lets allow all characters in the domain name. so i would match from 'http' to the next single slash.

Comment: @clamp: I don't understand your intentions. Would you like to match intentionally wrong urls?

Comment: @SilentGhost no not wrong urls, but could be intranet urls without TLD endings.

Comment: @SilentGhost OK, I've forgotten than '-' is a domain name characters.

Comment: Well, if any one is still interested, actionscript [happens to follow ECMAScript edition 3 regex](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ea9.html).  So it will be a lot like (if not identical to) javascript.

Comment: @SilentGhost i am afraid it really doesnt work for me. i also tried it here: http://regexpal.com/

Comment: @clamp: I'm sorry I don't know what you've tried or tested. I've tested it (in python) and it clearly works. You understand that you need to extract a captured group, right?